# What is wrong with this proof? Claim: $\ln(2)$ is rational.

Tags: proof-verification, induction, proof-explanation

> Claim: $\ln 2$ is a rational number. (Note that $\ln 2 = 1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$). This is done by proving that $\ln 2 = 1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$ is rational.
>
> Proof by induction on $n$:
>
> *Base case*:
>
> $n = 1$: 1 is obviously rational.
>
> *Inductive hypothesis*:
>
> Suppose that $1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k$ is rational.
>
> *Inductive step*:
>
> We need to show that $1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{k+1}$ is a rational number. Observe that $1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{k+1} = (1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k) + \frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{k+1}$. By the induction hypothesis, $1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k$ is a rational number. Furthermore, $\frac{(-1)^{k+2}}{k+1}$ is a rational number, as it can be expressed as a fraction. Thus, summing two rational numbers will result in another rational number, and by induction we have proven that $\ln 2$ is rational.

My thoughts are

- First, in the *inductive step*, we should state that this holds for some $n$.
- Second, we know that $\ln(2)$ is irrational.
- This seems really sound, but I just can't find the mistake in the induction proof.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not following.  An infinite (convergent) sum of rationals can obviously be irrational.  Is that the question?

Comment: Induction only proves that each partial sum is rational, but says (and cannot say) anything about the limit.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with convergence of sequences to infinity, can we express the sum of rationals by always $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+cb}{bd}$? Or am I overthinking it.

Comment: @1011011010010100011 `can't you just say that the sum of rationals is always` Any ***finite*** sum of rationals is a rational. Any ***real*** number, including irrationals, can be represented as an ***infinite*** sum of rationals, just think the decimal representation for example.

Comment: Every real number (hence every irrational) has a decimal expansion.  That gives you a sum of rationals that converges to the desired real number.

Comment: What is true for the finite is not necessarily true for the infinite.  Every irrational number can be expressed as an infinite sum of rational numbers.

Comment: Every irrational is the limit of a sequence of rationals, for instance its decimal expansion.  Induction prove that a statement is true for every natural number.  It doesn't say anything about what happens at "infinity."

Comment: The same erroneous reasoning shows that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n$ is finite.  Indeed, for any natural $n$ the summation yields a finite number...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What the induction proves (somewhat verbosely, possibly to hide that not much is really happening) is that *each of the partial sums* is a rational number, which is true.

But $\log 2$ is the *limit* of the partial sums, and the limit of a sequence of rationals is not necessarily rational.

---

In fact, it is well known that *every* real number is the sum of a series of rationals. For example,

$$ \pi = 3 + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{4}{100} + \frac{1}{1000} + \frac{5}{10000} + \frac{9}{100000} + \cdots $$

Answer (score 1):

You proved that every partial sum is rational, that is, $\log(2)$ is the limit of a rational sequence. But the rational numbers set is not closed in the real numbers set, it means that exists sequences of rational numbers that converge to a irrational number.

In this case, the rational sequence of the partial sums converge to irrational limit $\log(2)$.